# Changing The BG Image on Scroll

Tags: jquery, css, image

Basically I want the background image to change when the user scrolls up or down. I know this can be done with jquery, I'm just not experience enough to know how exactly. Any ideas?

Comment: This should get you started: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/ :)

Comment: You will also need this: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of `.scroll()` and `.css()` working together ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9rnM7/)):

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
  $("#TheCage").css(
    {
        'display': 'block',
        'background-image': 'url(http://www.placecage.com/300/200)'
    }).fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $("#TheCage").css({'background-image': 'none'})
      });
  }
);
```